# Changing a constant inside function from another function

Tags: python

I have 2 functions in my code. When I call the second function, the first function calculates "z" and returns it together with "m". In the second function I have to check "z" first and if it's lower than 150, I have to add 1 to "m" and recalculate "z".

How can I pass "m + 1" as the new "m" to the first function so when it recalculates "z", it considers "m + 1" and not "m"?

```
def r(x, y):
    m = 1
    z = x + y + m
    return m, z


def n():
    m, z = r(3, 4)
    if z < 150:
        m = m + 1
        m1, z1 = r(5, 6)
    print(m, m1, z1)


n()
```

Comment: You have to further parameterize `r`, so that `m` is *also* a parameter, not a local constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `m` as a paramater with a default value:

```
def r(x, y, m=1):
    z = x + y + m
    return m, z


def n():
    m, z = r(3, 4)
    if z < 150:
        m = m + 1
        m1, z1 = r(5, 6, m)
    print(m, m1, z1)


n()
```